# ucspi-tcp writing received data to a file

Tags: linux, shell, sockets, tcp

I'm using ucspi-tcp program to setting up a TCP Server.
http://cr.yp.to/ucspi-tcp.html

It's working great when I need to read data from file and send it to all clients (shell script included below), but now I need an opposite situation. I need to read data from a client and save it to the file.

**I'm currently running:**

```
tcpserver -v -RHl0 IP PORT /var/www/vhosts/domain.com/tcpserv/script.sh
```

**script.sh:**

```
#!/bin/sh
cat /var/www/vhosts/domain.com/httpdocs/file.txt
sleep 120
```

Sorry for my english, thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**
I've changed the script.sh to:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "$0 - $1 - $2 - $3 - $4" > /var/www/vhosts/domain.com/httpdocs/text.txt
sleep 120
```

but the result is:

```
/var/www/vhosts/domain.com/tcpserver/script.sh -  -  -  - .
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't tried `ucspi-tcp` by myself, but I think this should work for you.

```
#!/bin/sh
cat - > /var/www/vhosts/domain.com/httpdocs/text.txt
```

If you prefer processing the input line-by-line, use curly brackets to redirect all the outputs from a block of code.

```
#!/bin/sh
{
    while read line; do
        echo $line
    done
} > /var/www/vhosts/domain.com/httpdocs/text.txt
```